# Homework: Restriction on |z+1|+|z-1|=2, z∈C

Tags: complex-numbers

After simplifying the relation $|z+1| + |z-1| = 2, z∈\mathbb{C}$ to $\Im(z)=0$, I plotted the original relation on my TI-nspire calculator and WolframAlpha. As expected it simplifies to $\Im(z)=0$ however both stated that the relation exists where $-1 < Re(z) < 1$. Can someone explain how this restriction can be found when simplifying the relation?

[Here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cz%2B1%7C%2B%7Cz-1%7C%3D2) a link to the relation plotted on WolframAlpha.

Comment: the only solution for this is the line segment $[-1,1].$ if you increase the rhs, you get an ellipse with foci at $\pm 1$

Comment: Please post your simplification to $\Im(z)=0$ that you said you had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the triangle inequality: $2=|z+1|+|z-1|\geq |z+1+z-1|=2|z|$.

Hence we know even before doing any more sophisticated computation that $|z|\leq 1$, which when $z$ is real translates into the restriction you mention.

Comment: This makes sense, although how did you get that |z+1+z-1| is the other side of the triangle?

Comment: @Adam: The triangle inequality states that $|a|+|b|\geq|a+b|$. In this case $a=z+1$ and $b=z-1$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way you have that $$-1\leq\Re(z)+\Im (z)\leq1$$ Since
$$|z+1|+|z-1|=\sqrt{(\Re(z)+1)^2+\Im(z)^2}+\sqrt{(\Re(z)-1)^2+\Im(z)^2}$$
Now if $$\Re(z)>1$$ than $$2\leq\sqrt{(1+1)^2+\Im(z)^2}<\sqrt{(\Re(z)+1)^2+\Im(z)^2}$$ and if $$\Re(z)<-1$$ than $$2\leq\sqrt{(-1-1)^2+\Im(z)^2}<\sqrt{(\Re(z)-1)^2+\Im(z)^2}$$

Comment: The first line cannot be correct. $\Im(z)=0$, as Eric Stucky pointed out, then any $-1\le\Re(z)\le1$ will work.

Comment: @user1537366: It's reasonable to assume this is a typo and $-1$ was intended. (But I don't see why we would have it, unless we know $\mathfrak I(z)=0$.)

Comment: OK, but then it is still not clear how the second line results in the first except by the triangle inequality which you did. In fact the other triangle inequality using $|1-z|$ instead gives an equality condition which only holds when $\Im(z)=0$ as needed.